# Post to a different page but stay on the current page

Tags: php, post, target

I have a requirement, 2 php pages, one for entry purposes and another for display purposes.

Page 1- badgeentry.php allows an admin to enter badges numbers 123 and clicks submit. 
Page 2 - badgedisplay.php allows all other users to view what the current badge number is. In this case 123. This page is using the "Refresh" meta html tag.

As far as the development, I have badgeentry and badgedisplay coded for. However, I want admins to stay on badgeentry after submit is clicked and still post data to badgedisplay. How can I do that?

Also, how do i maintain the badge number until the number is updated by admin. Currently, I lose the post value on badgedisplay page.

PS: I cannot use databases, maybe Javascript if I really have to

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looking into jQuery .ajax() function?

Comment: How do you suppose to pass data to badgedisplay? Where does that page pull data from?

Answer (score 5):

**With JavaScript:** Use AJAX to post asynchronously in the background.

**Without JavaScript:** Post to a hidden iframe (with `<form target="name-of-iframe">`)